# Creating shapes inside collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am working on a project of mine that populates 5 items based on data returned from a MySQL database.  My issue is I need to make each item a circle or square based on the data returned.

When running the following:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
_collectionView=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:layout];
[_collectionView setDataSource:self];
[_collectionView setDelegate:self];

[_collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
[_collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
CGRect frame = [_collectionView frame];
[_collectionView setFrame:CGRectMake(10,
                                         5,
                                         300,
                                         frame.size.height - 100)];
[self.view addSubview:_collectionView];
```

..A custom layout that creates a square is called.  My question is how can I make it a square or a circle inside of the cell creation function?

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 .... do my creation of circle or square in here 
}
```

instead of in here:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    return CGSizeMake(50, 50);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would subclass `UICollectionViewCell` and put the drawing code inside the subclass, in `drawRect:`

Once you create the actual class you use it by doing something like

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier";
    // set custom properties here
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of where to call?  What I mean is where I would subview the `UICollectionViewCell` within my cell creation.

Answer (score 1):

No need to get all crazy and subclass anything.

1. Design your cells as a square (the default).
2. In sizeForRowAtIndex (i'm typing in my phone, so i dont remember the exact name), do your logic to know when to make a circle.
3. When you need to make a circle just do cell.layer.cornerRadius = cell.frame.size.width/2; (this will make it a circle).
4. Else, reset the square (do the same thing as above, but set the radius to 0).

This approach will keep your code modular